# Change colors after drawing lines in Pangolin using OpenGL

Tags: opengl, c++

I am drawing a bunch of lines using pangolin library. Each line has 4 vertex pairs. My goal is to give each line a different colour. Here is the code snippet I am using. In each render loop I do the following -

```
    Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1> color[4] = {{255,0,0,255}, {0,255,0,255}, {0,0,255,255}, {255,255,255,255}};
    int index = 0;
    for (const auto pair : vertexPairs) {
        glColor4ubv(color[index++].data());
        auto point1 = pair.first;
        auto point2 = pair.second;
        pangolin::glDrawLine(static_cast<float>(point1(0)),
                             static_cast<float>(point1(1)),
                             static_cast<float>(point1(2)),
                             static_cast<float>(point2(0)),
                             static_cast<float>(point2(1)),
                             static_cast<float>(point2(2)));
    }
```

For each line, I update the stack using `glColor4ubv()` with a different colour. But I dont see different colours. Is this correct way to update the colours for each line.

[image]